# How can you tell an appointment is a meeting?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook form region for meetings in an Outlook add-in using VSTO.

My region factory looks like this:

```
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClass(Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionMessageClassAttribute.Appointment)]
[Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionName("Notices.MeetingRegion")]
public partial class MeetingRegionFactory
{
    // Occurs before the form region is initialized.
    // To prevent the form region from appearing, set e.Cancel to true.
    // Use e.OutlookItem to get a reference to the current Outlook item.
    private void MeetingRegionFactory_FormRegionInitializing(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.FormRegionInitializingEventArgs e)
    {

        var appointment = e.OutlookItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        // is appointment a meeting or just an appointment?

    }
}
```

I need to show the form region only for meetings, I don't want to show the form region for plain appointments.

How can I tell appointment is a meeting or just a plain appointment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to check the [MeetingStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.meetingstatus.aspx) property of the AppointmentItem. The status should show [olNonMeeting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olmeetingstatus.aspx) for simple appointments without attendees.